# Where do I find Apache's configtest declaration?

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to improve security of my Apache webserver.

1. Open:

   ```
   /etc/apache2/conf.d/security
   ```
2. Edit:

   ```
   ServerTokens Prod
   ServerSignature Off
   ```
3. Reload/Restart:

   ```
   /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
   /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
   ```

The values Prod and Off should be fine, but I get these errors:

```
ServerTokens takes one argument, Determine tokens displayed in the Server: header - Min(imal), OS or Full
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

```
ServerSignature takes one argument, En-/disable server signature (on|off|email)
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

Where do I find Apache's configtest declaration, so I can tell it to accept Prod and Off?

**Problem solution:**

I had inline comments in my config file, which are not allowed.

So do NOT do this:

```
ServerTokens Prod # Added this on 10/20/2012
```

Instead do it this way:

```
# Added this on 10/20/2012:
ServerTokens Prod
```

However, the error messages confused me, since they only had three options (Min, OS and Full) and were all lower case (on|off|email) while in the config file there were more options and ucfirst.

Comment: Look the string `configtest` in `/etc/init.d/apache2`. It will run the command `apachectl configtest`. Then follow it from there.

Comment: Also, the `configtest` command is telling you that you have a syntax error in your configuration file. You do not need to fix `configtest`, you need to fix the errors which configtest is showing you.

Comment: Sure, my fault. But the error messages confused me. Thought there might be something wrong in configtest itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like you're using a Debian/Ubuntu or similar system. You can run a configtest with

```
apache2ctl configtest
```

You can't change it's declaration to accept Prod (it already does) and you shouldn't need to.

The Error message is quite clear  `ServerTokens takes one argument ...`  I can only get this error message if I supply the ServerTokens directive with more than one parameter so

```
 ServerTokens Prod 1
```

fails in the same way that you observe. You need to figure out why your ServerTokens and ServerSignature directives have more than one parameter. This first thing I would try is to load the files into vim and use `:set invlist` which will show any hidden characters in your file.

Comment: +1 for pointing me to the right direction

Comment: @user1438038: For completeness what was it ?

Comment: Just added my solution above.

Comment: Check for spaces

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean.
`apache2 configtest` (on a redhat box) runs apachectl.
If you look at apachectl which is s script supplied by apache it is bascially running httpd -t.

So httpd itself is what is testing the config when you run a configtest.

One way around this would be to put some negated `ifdefine`s around the offeneding config stanzas

e.g.:
In your config file:

```
<ifdefine ! DONTRUNMYBADCONFIG >
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
</ifdefine>
```

Then run

```
httpd -t -DDONTRUNMYBADCONFIG
```

To test your config.
I believe ewverything else will get tested normally, but those two directives will be ignored as long as `-DDONTRUNMYBADCONFIG` is in the apache command line.

You could add the `-DDONTRUNMYBADCONFIG` to the `/etc/init.d/apache2` script in the "confgitest" section if you wanted, so you could still run `service httpd configtest` as normal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not what I want.